# typescript parseInt() results in compile error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am fairly new to typescript, and I am trying to simply remove an object from an array that I fetch from a mysql database, here is how I try to do it,

```js
// this is the format of the fetched data
let permissions = [
    {
        id: '1',
        permission: 'permission one'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        permission: 'permission two'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        permission: 'permission three'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        permission: 'permission four'
    },
]

permissions = permissions.filter(permission => {
    return parseInt(permission.id, 10) !== 2      // 2 is just an example
});
```

when I try this way, I get the following compile error

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

---

I also tried the following, but strangely enough, it always removes the last index!

```js
const removeIndex = permissions
       .map(item => item.id)
       .indexOf(2);  // also 2 is an example 
   
permissions.splice(removeIndex, 1);
```

could someone please tell me where the error is?
and also which one of the two methods is more performant?
thanks in advance

Comment: but this works fine in my chrome console

Comment: It works perfectly fine in an online typescript compiler such as https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Wich Typescript version do you use? works in mine without problems

Comment: @JochenKühner, this code not even have TypeScript code, this is pure javaScript

Comment: yes I know, I tested it, and it works fine with me too in an online typescript editor, however in my project it does what I explained above, the type script version is `"typescript": "^3.4.3"`

Comment: also this is a nestjs application, one of the installed packages is `nest/node`, I am not sure if this info is relevant or no !!

Comment: The last snippet removes the last one because `2` is not in the array (`"2"` is), therefore `indexOf` returns `-1` and `splice(-1, 1)` removes the last element. Your first snippet should work, maybe someone broke the compiler again.

Comment: @DupinderSingh this is the exact error with the error code `error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try this instead

```
permissions = permissions.filter(permission => +permission.id !== 2);
```

The [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator is perfect here to evaluate a string as a number

Comment: well it did work, could you please explain why or provide me with a link that does that!! thanks very much anyway :)

Comment: i too want to know, why it works,  but in my case, i was running script in V8 engine and its was working fine

Comment: @MoSwilam & @DupinderSingh in my sample code the `+identifier` syntax is really saying "eval the value of identifier as a number" (c.f. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

There are likely other ways this could be achieved:

```ts
new Number(identifier);
Number.parseInt(identifier);
Number.parseInt(identifier, 10);
```

The `parseInt(identifier)` and `parseInt(identifier, 10)` are also syntactically correct and should work.

Comment: @PopGoesTheWza, this is really helpful and useful, thanks mate, cheers!.